# How do I use AeroFS to transfer a file once, not sync forever?

Tags: aerofs

I want to transfer (copy) a very large folder to another computer using AeroFS.  **Specifically:**

1. I want to keep the copy on the original computer.
2. I want the copy on the original computer to be completely read only
3. I want to eventually move the folder on the new computer and make changes inside it without the original computer being touched.

AeroFS seems to make this very difficult:

1. Suppose you move the folder out of the AeroFS folder, then the folder on the original computer gets deleted instantly.
2. Instead you might try unchecking the "selective sync" checkbox for the folder in question.  This does not blow away the folder on the original computer, but it does immediately blow away the folder on the new computer.
3. You might try this: turn OFF AeroFS on the new computer.  Move the folder out of the AeroFS folder, and NEVER EVER turn on AeroFS again until you get back to the original computer.  Once at the original computer, turn off AeroFS and move the original folder out of the AeroFS folder so it doesn't get blown away.
4. An excruciating work around is to temporarily create two copies of the sync'ed folder on the new computer (one inside the AeroFS folder, another outside).  Theoretically then, you could follow procedure 2. and still have one copy left on the new computer.  This simply does not work though once the folder becomes large enough.

Does AeroFS simply not have a better way to do this?  The AeroFS website claims to make transferring large files secure and easy, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this can probably be best achieved using the 'Sharing' feature.  AeroFS lets you right click on a file in your AeroFS folder and select "AeroFS > Share this Folder" and typing an email address.  The purpose of this feature is for sharing with people you know.
I had overlooked this because I am transferring a file with myself.

When you 'Share this Folder' it gives you the option of having the other person be a "Viewer", which means their changes don't propagate back.